# Paypal Express Checkout not sending money now live

Tags: express, paypal, checkout

Please help. I have recently updated the paypal express checkout system on my website (where it leaves the website to go to paypal for payment, then returns).

It was all working fine in sandbox. I went to put it live, and I have found the correct API credentials, but it won't work.

It takes me to the paypal page fine. It takes payment and returns me to the payment return url. All fine. But no payment actually moves anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?!

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's really nothing in your question that would help us help you...aside from "re-check everything" in your setup and ensure that whatever was in "sandbox" mode is set to "production/live" (because as you stated, "sandbox was working").

Comment: Thomas, please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're working with to help folks understand your problem and get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It takes me to the paypal page fine. It takes payment and returns me to the payment return url. All fine. But no payment actually moves anywhere.

From you declaring that, it seems that you are either not performing the DoExpressCheckout API call, which is the call that moves the money, OR you are getting an error with your DoExpressCheckout call.  The flow and error codes for Express Checkout can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

Answer (score 1):

On PayPal pay attention to the button text -

If it reads "Agree and Pay" - then you have configured PayPal to take payment

If it reads "Agree and Continue" then you have only set up the transaction but PayPal is waiting for you to send a confirmation to take payment (there is no DoExpressCheckoutCall)